# How to substitute pipe dependent on the previous command exit code?

Tags: bash

I have following line in the script:

```
maim -s | tee $fname > last.png
```

`maim -s` takes screenshot and returns 0 if it was taken succesfully or 1 if it was cancelled. The problem is, if it returns 0, it pipes zero bytes anyway so after cancelling i have two empty files `$fname` and `last.png`.

I want to redirect output to /dev/null if `maim -s` returns 0 right on the place, without writing to temporary file and copying it to `$fname` and `last.png` if it isn't empty.
How do I do that?

Comment: All commands in a pipeline run in parallel. Because they're started at the same time, the second one can't possibly know if the first one succeeded.

Comment: BTW, consider *renaming* rather than *copying* -- that's an atomic operation.

Comment: dam, that's right... so, only temporary file then?

Comment: You need to buffer somewhere -- either a temporary file or in memory.